# Trying to write a can it construct function getting a ValueError: substring not found error

Tags: python

```
def canConstruct(target, wordBank):

        if target == '': #if there are no words in wordBank
            return True

        for word in wordBank:
            if target.index(word) == 0: #checks if current word is current targets prefix
                suffix = target.removeprefix(word)
                if canConstruct(suffix, wordBank) == True:
                    return True

        return False

    print(canConstruct("eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeef",["e","ee","eee","eeee","eeeee","eeeeee","eeeeeee"] ))
```

i dont get why it is throwing this error

```
ValueError: substring not found
```

Comment: `target.index(word) == 0` --> `target.find(word) == 0`

Answer (score 1):

Note that: `removesuffix()` is only available after Python v3.9. [Doc](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#str.removesuffix)

So if you are on earlier version, I think you can simply adjust your code as below:

```
def canConstruct(target, wordBank):
    if (target == ''): return True
    for word in wordBank:
        if (target.startswith(word)):
            suffix = target[len(word):]
            if (canConstruct(suffix, wordBank) == 0):
                return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because of this line:

```
if target.index(word) == 0:
```

If you pass a substring into the index method, and that substring doesn't exist within the superstring, than this error would occur.

For instance, if:

```
target = 'test string'
word = 'z'
```

When we try to index() *target* for *word*, the index() method won't be able to find *word* within *target* and will raise the exception you are having.

It's possible you simply have this line reversed, and are instead wanting to find *target* within *word*.

In that case you'll want to do this instead:

```
if word.index(target) == 0:
```

Comment: but it throws the same error because it doesnt find the target within word maybe there is another way of doing this i just dont know how

Comment: omg sorry there is literally a method called startswith() that does what i want to

Answer (score 0):

```
def canConstruct(target, wordBank):

    if target == '':
        return True

    for word in wordBank:
        if target.startswith(word):
            suffix = target.removeprefix(word)
            if canConstruct(suffix, wordBank) == True:
                return True

    return False


print(canConstruct("abcdef", ["ab", "abc", "cd", "def", "abcd", ]))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).